# Access object from object within the object

Tags: java, object

I try to program a small feed-forward neural network in oop java.
I have three different classes called layer, synapse and neuron.
One layer consists of a variable amount of nodes.
Each Synapse has a start and end-neuron and also a weight.
Now I want to access each weight attribute of the ingoing synapses from within the neurons. Somehow I can't wrap my mind around this.
Am I missing something?
I also tried working with a weighted graph, but I don't exactly know how to do it.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Ha "wrap my mind around" neural networks

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. As of now, your question will not fly. It is too broad; and you seem to be under the false impression that this is a service that walks you through the whole process of determining your exact requirements, designing and implementing a solution ...

Comment: Hey @GhostCat,
I can understand your point of view. My question really doesn't look like I thought about the problem. However,  I found and tried several solutions for my problem in before, but I wasn't really happy with the design. I stuck with one of them now.

Also please notice that this is nothing I need for an assignment or other work for my university. I just startred studying and we're still doing simple stuff so I thought I can try something more difficult.

Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: My main point is: it is close to impossible to help with such input. You should consider condensing your problem to a [mcve] for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like all you need to do is keep a reference within each object to the the objects to which each is connected and have appropriate getters and setters.

This means from any object you can just move forward and backward along your NN.

So if your neuron has a reference to every incoming synapse (i.e a List) you can then call a Synapse.getWeight() function by accessing the Synapse from within your collection.

Comment: Yes, I had this idea before. However, i also want to write a method to create a neural network which means I have to add all my synapses and neurons through loops. Finding and adding all the belonging synapses to the neurons automatically is a real pain then...

Comment: No make them call a method which adds themselves when they are added i.e neuron.setSynapse(Synapse s) which would add s to the list then on creation of a synapse you can call Neuron.setSynapse(this) on the reference of the neuron